# наложение полоски на фотo CSS

Tags: css, css3, html5

Помогите наложить полоску на фото, но так чтобы справа полоска обрезала фото

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я предполагаю этот вопрос можно решить с помощью `clippath`.
Для более точного создания `clippath` я использую онлайн-генератор - https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Вот как выглядит код с `clippath`:

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent{
  display:flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: url("https://lexusenthusiast.com/images/weblog/15-12-01-lexus-japan-pre-orders.jpg") center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.parent > div{
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  z-index:1;
  
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(80% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 60% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(80% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 60% 100%);
  
  background-color: #3e506d;
}

.parent > div > div{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  z-index:2;
  
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(80% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 60% 100%);
clip-path: polygon(85% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 65% 100%);
  
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: этот момент возможно сделать адаптивным?

Comment: @ВиталийШонов Зависит от того как вы будуте представлять адаптивность. А вообще - мой код уже "адаптивный". Точнее резиновый) размеры разделителей и самой картинки зависит от размера экрана